# How to check state of NSCheckbox created programmatically in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I created Multiple checkbox dynamic, now I want to check state of them but I don't know how to do that. This is my code to create multiple NSCheckbox:

```
for(int i=1; i<=number;i++)
{
    DeleteCheckbox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (20,textfield_Y,50,25)];
    [DeleteCheckbox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [DeleteCheckbox setBezelStyle:0];
    [DeleteCheckbox setTitle:@""];
    [DeleteCheckbox setTag:200+i];
    [DeleteCheckbox setState:NSOffState];
    [DeleteCheckbox setAction:@selector(checkState:)];
    [guiView addSubview:DeleteCheckbox];
    [DeleteCheckbox release];
}
```

And below code for check state:

```
-(IBAction)checkState:(id)sender
{
    if ([DeleteCheckbox state] == NSOnState) {

        NSLog(@"selected");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"not selected");

    }
}
```

But when run, it always printf: "not selected".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check the state of the *sending button*, not of the instance variable `DeleteCheckbox` (which has been released and does not point to a valid button):

```
-(IBAction)checkState:(NSButton *)sender
{
    if ([sender state] == NSOnState) {
        NSLog(@"selected");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"not selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me more one times,please? I updated my question? Thanks

Comment: @user2656381: Please post a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: Thanks, i posted new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120748/how-to-add-tag-of-nscheckbox-created-dynamic-to-array-in-cocoa. Please help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: It wasn't really released because `guiView` is keeping a reference to it: `DeleteCheckbox` just points to the last button, which is a valid one but not often the one you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You set the "Off" state here :

```
[DeleteCheckbox setState:NSOffState];
```

Try to set "On" state instead.

```
[DeleteCheckbox setState:NSOnState];
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to first loading they set OFFstate.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the state of the `sender`, not of `DeleteCheckBox`, since you seem to be reusing that variable for all checkboxes you want to instantiate.

```
  if ([(NSButton*)sender state] == NSOnState)
```

etc...