# How to Add tag of NSCheckbox created dynamically to Array in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I created Multiple checkbox dynamic and set tag for it, Now I want to check if it checked, add its tag to NSArray. 
This is my code to create mutiple NSCheckbox:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    DeleteCheckbox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (20,textfield_Y,50,25)];
    [DeleteCheckbox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [DeleteCheckbox setBezelStyle:0];
    [DeleteCheckbox setTitle:@""];
    [DeleteCheckbox setTag:200+i];
    [DeleteCheckbox setState:NSOffState];
    [DeleteCheckbox setAction:@selector(checkState:)];
    [guiView addSubview:DeleteCheckbox];
    [DeleteCheckbox release];
}
```

I used this code but it add all to Array:

```
-(IBAction)checkState:(NSButton *)sender
{
    if ([sender state] == NSOnState) {
        NSLog(@"selected");
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i ++) {
            [deleteSelectedArray addObject: [[guiView viewWithTag:200+i] intValue]];

        }
        NSLog(@"deleteSelectedArray : %@",deleteSelectedArray);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"not selected");
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) checkState: (NSButton*) sender {
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i ++) {
        if ([[guiView viewWithTag: 200 + i] state] == NSOnState) {
            [deleteSelectedArray addObject: [[guiView viewWithTag: 200 + i] intValue]];
        }
    }
}
```